# how access to Object with dynamics proprierties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example suppose to have this object a I print with JSON.stringify:

```
var element={"name":"Hugo","age":20,"items":[{"id":"student__0","dog__0":"3}{"id":"student__1","dog__1":2}]};
```

So I have in my jquery code two for and I want to built the name of string:

```
for(var i=0,i<student_number;i++){
var label="student__"+i;
//no my code give me error and I don't know how access
//want to show that the value of "student__0"

console.log(element['items'][i].label);

}
```

Comment: It might be that the property that contains "student__0" is id not label, so: `console.log(element['items'][i].id);` should work... If you want to set it to the label variable then `element.items[i].id = label;` should work

Comment: yes but I have build my "id" with for index, Can it possibile or not?

Comment: yes, if you need to access it dynamically you could do `console.log(element['items'][i][label]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access the property using the `var label`, you could do

```
for(var i=0,i<student_number;i++){
var label="student__"+i;
console.log(element['items'][i][label]); //note the label is in bracket notation not dot notation

}
```

This does rely on your object key being called "student__0" not "id".

If you are just trying to access the id property then:

```
for(var i=0,i<student_number;i++){
    var label="student__"+i;
    console.log(element['items'][i].id);
}
```

should suffice

Comment: I think you should use 'id' within quotes.... console.log(element['items'][i]['id']) as because id is keyword.